# Tutorials for using jquery and ajax to render partials in rails 3.2?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've been looking everywhere for the past few days now and all the tutorials I've been able to find either

- don't work for rails 3.2,
- are old,
- or I can't understand.

I need someone or a set of instructions that will teach me how to render partials with jQuery as well as where I should put the javascript code.