# Ruby on Rails: Calling controller method from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller

Is it possible to call controller method from a javascript? I mean it's not from view(html.erb) also not from js.erb. I want to call method from .js file, which in public folder. Thank you

Comment: It is possible.....Short Question and what all you get is Such a Short Answer

Comment: If you don't mind, would you tell me how? or just give a hint. because I spent hours looking for it and got nothing. thank you

Comment: it depends on your requirement.....though Ajax is Best way to do it

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933261/how-to-call-a-rails-method-from-in-jquery.
This answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to do AJAX calls. You probably want to use jquery which would be simpler than straight javascript. Here is a [link to a w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) on jquery AJAX calls. Here is another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424318/tutorials-for-using-jquery-and-ajax-to-render-partials-in-rails-3-2) with a link to a gist with some example code or you may want to Google jQuery, AJAX and Rails 3.